# Establecer Ruta de RED de manera estica de manera permanente en Debian, Ubuntu o derivados

Tags: linux, configuración

tengo un problema y es que por alguna razón no consigo que me ponga una ruta de manera **permanente** en el sistema operativo.
He buscado información y he encontrado varios métodos que todos vienen a decir lo mismo, y es que en el "/etc/network/interfaces" se debe configurar unas líneas que dejo más abajo.
**Basicamente necesito que todo lo que vaya a la red X.X.120.X, vaya para la X.X.33.1**

```
up /sbin/ip route add 192.168.120.0/24 via 192.168.33.1 dev eth0
down /sbin/ip route delete 192.168.120.0/24 via 192.168.33.1 dev eth0
```

Dejo aquí "**uname -a**" por si alguien quiere saber exactamente la versión de linux que tengo.

```
Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u3 (2019-06-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Dejo aquí el archivo de configuración. ¿A alguien se le ocurre que puedo estar haciendo mal o alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto enp4s0
allow-hotplug enp4s0
#iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 192.168.2.22
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 192.168.33.22
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.33.1

### static ip config START ##
up /sbin/ip route add 192.168.120.0/24 via 192.168.33.1 dev eth0
down /sbin/ip route delete 192.168.120.0/24 via 192.168.33.1 dev eth0
## static ip config END ##
```

**Cualquier cosa para mejorar la pregunta me decís, un Saludo y Gracias de Antemano**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregar así en tu archivo de configuracion:

```
ip route add 192.168.120.0/24 via 192.168.33.1 dev eth0
```

Porque tienes la siguiente IP route? Esta especificado habilitar esa ruta en alguna otra parte?

```
down /sbin/ip route delete 192.168.120.0/24 via 192.168.33.1 dev eth0
```

Si es posible, comparte las rutas que tienes configuradas.

```
# netstat -r
```